# Dataloader Upserting: the Child overwrites the parent

Tags: data-loader, account, externalid, child-to-parent

I'm using Dataloader to Upsert a Child Account to Parent Account using an external ID.

When the Upsert is complete, **the Child overwrites the parent**, it's not not connecting the Child Account to the Parent Account.

((See Answer Below))

Answer (score 2):

You should only be selecting your External Id field in Step 2b. You don't want to match the child records *to* the parent records and update them; you want to connect their lookup relationship.

Step 1 is identifying existing copies of *this* record in your database.

Comment: I don't have Data Loader in front of me, but yes, I believe that's correct. You _don't_ want to match inbound Accounts (and they won't match on Id, because those Ids don't exist in the target org); you want to match `ParentId` only.

Comment: I'll do my best to take a look and repro but it may be a while. Full schedule today.

Comment: Answer below!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

How to Upsert **Child Accounts** to **Parent Accounts** Using Dataloader:

[image]